# Как правильно настроить git в zendstudio, если проект добавлен из удалённого сервера (remote server)?

Tags: git, symfony

В данный момент проект symfony организован следущим образом:

- **release version** - проект размещен на удалённом сервере в отдельном каталоге, доступен через веб-браузер широкой аудитории, имеет git репозиторий, ветка release
- **develop version** -  на том же сервере, но в другом каталоге,  доступен через веб-браузер для разработчиков через авторизацию, является git клоном release version, ветка develop.

Непосредственно разработка ведётся с помощью zendstudio на локальной машине. Проект подключен через "new project from remote server". Все изменения автоматически заливаются на удалённый сервер в директорию с develop version.

На локальной машине осуществляется контроль версий с помощью git в zendstudio. При этом, после первоначальной загрузки проекта с удаленного сервера использовался git репозиторий, который скачался с удаленного сервера вместе с другими файлами из дирректории с develop version (т.е. не через git clone).

У такой конфигурации при первых испытаниях проявились ошибки:

- на локальной машине пришлось заново настраивать путь для fetch и push в release version, т.к. он изначально был относительным и в рамках одной машины, а с локальной нужно было настроить ssh
- новый код синхронизируется между локальной машиной и develop version на удаленном сервере, а вот git репозиторий нет, из-за чего git в develop version на удаленном сервере не имеет никаких коммитов, веток и пр, живет своей жизнью, хоть и хранится в том же каталоге, что и постоянно обновляемый код...
- есть подозрение, что с локальной машины заливаются мета файлы, которые впоследствии конфликтуют с develop version на удалённом сервере

Вопрос: как лучше организовать архитектуру и репозитории, таким образом, чтобы продолжать использовать zendstudio project from remote server, т.к. нет желания ставить все пакеты, базы данных и пр на локальной машине.